# Problems copying content in Safari Developer Mode

Tags: safari

When using Safari Developer Mode, I've encountered two oddities:

1. "Search" tab: Enter a search, click search result (left), then mark text in source viewer (middle), then click Ctrl+C (or right-click and select Copy). Result : *Entire* source is copied.
2. "Elements" tab: Highlight link: Right-click and select "Copy Link Address". Result: *Nothing* is copied.

Am I using it wrong, or are these in fact bugs in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari Technology Preview 61 fixes one of the issues. Per the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/):

> **Web Inspector**
>
> - Fixed copy from Search results content view

---

These would appear to be bugs in Safari, I can reproduce them in Safari Technology Preview 58. You can report bugs to Apple by following the steps at [developer.apple.com/bug-reporting](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Comment: Posted both of them.

Comment: @forthrin A bug has been fixed! Edited answer

Comment: Good to see that ones reports make it back to the responsible programmer. Did you test this? I don't use betas.